# OpenCV won't compile due to unresolved externals -- LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, unresolved-external, lnk2019

I am brand new to OpenCV and have been trying to set it up in Visual Studios 2010 Ultimate. I have followed the documentation exactly, and linked the files as it said. Here are the additional libraries that I am using:

```
opencv_core231d.lib
opencv_imgproc231d.lib
opencv_highgui231d.lib
opencv_ml231d.lib
opencv_video231d.lib
opencv_features2d231d.lib
opencv_calib3d231d.lib
opencv_objdetect231d.lib
opencv_contrib231d.lib
opencv_legacy231d.lib
opencv_flann231d.lib
```

And all of their Release counterparts. However, when I try to debug & compile the sample code given to me, I get the following errors. (I read somewhere that you have to compile and publish the project in order for it to work properly? Is that true as well?)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: openCVTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 5/6/2012 10:39:03 AM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\openCVTest.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvWaitKey referenced in function _main
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0_InputArray@cv@@QAE@ABVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvMoveWindow referenced in function _main
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::namedWindow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?namedWindow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function _main
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual double __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::get(int)" (?get@VideoCapture@cv@@UAENH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture(void)" (??1VideoCapture@cv@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::isOpened(void)const " (?isOpened@VideoCapture@cv@@UBE_NXZ) referenced in function _main
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0VideoCapture@cv@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl cv::sum(class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?sum@cv@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@1@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function "double __cdecl getPSNR(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getPSNR@@YANABVMat@cv@@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class cv::MatExpr __thiscall cv::Mat::mul(class cv::_InputArray const &,double)const " (?mul@Mat@cv@@QBE?AVMatExpr@2@ABV_InputArray@2@N@Z) referenced in function "double __cdecl getPSNR(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getPSNR@@YANABVMat@cv@@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::convertTo(class cv::_OutputArray const &,int,double,double)const " (?convertTo@Mat@cv@@QBEXABV_OutputArray@2@HNN@Z) referenced in function "double __cdecl getPSNR(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getPSNR@@YANABVMat@cv@@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::absdiff(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &)" (?absdiff@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@0ABV_OutputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function "double __cdecl getPSNR(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getPSNR@@YANABVMat@cv@@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(class cv::Mat &)" (??0_OutputArray@cv@@QAE@AAVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function "double __cdecl getPSNR(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getPSNR@@YANABVMat@cv@@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl cv::mean(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?mean@cv@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@1@ABV_InputArray@1@0@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::_OutputArray const & __cdecl cv::noArray(void)" (?noArray@cv@@YAABV_OutputArray@1@XZ) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::divide(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,double,int)" (?divide@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@0ABV_OutputArray@1@NH@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::MatExpr __cdecl cv::operator+(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (??Hcv@@YA?AVMatExpr@0@ABVMat@0@0@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::MatExpr __cdecl cv::operator+(class cv::MatExpr const &,class cv::Scalar_<double> const &)" (??Hcv@@YA?AVMatExpr@0@ABV10@ABV?$Scalar_@N@0@@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::MatExpr __cdecl cv::operator*(double,class cv::Mat const &)" (??Dcv@@YA?AVMatExpr@0@NABVMat@0@@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::GaussianBlur(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::Size_<int>,double,double,int)" (?GaussianBlur@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@V?$Size_@H@1@NNH@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::copySize(class cv::Mat const &)" (?copySize@Mat@cv@@QAEXABV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::Mat(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>openCVTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::subtract(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,int)" (?subtract@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@0ABV_OutputArray@1@0H@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Mat & __cdecl cv::operator-=(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (??Zcv@@YAAAVMat@0@ABV10@0@Z)
1>C:\Users\Logan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\openCVTest\Debug\openCVTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 25 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.40
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I went through all my directories and made sure that the libraries, did in fact, exist in my OpenCV files, and my download didn't corrupt or anything. Any help would be appreciated!

-Logantf17

Comment: I need to know how well you know what you are doing. Do you know how to link against libraries? On the first look, it looks like that's exactly was is missing.

Comment: 1. have you compiled OpenCV yourself? 2. are the lib files under (Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies) in your visual c project?

Comment: Well, I am learning as I am going. I haven't needed to link to libraries before (this is the first time I have found it needed). I looked up how to link libraries in VS earlier, to make sure I was doing it right. But I don't know if anything else is necessary.. Such as header files or other libraries.

Comment: Yes, the lib files are in my visual c project. 

I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by compile by myself.

Comment: it is likely not opencv dependent. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487056/linking-library-in-visual-studio-2010, although there is no solution for the thread, make sure to have checked all the steps listed there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.3 C++ Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

shambool in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474218/unresolved-external-symbol-error-when-importing-libraries-for-opencv2-3-in-visua) just pointed that you should maybe read [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to).

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem and found that I was targeting a 32-bit platform.  The answer was to change my project to target x64.  The instructions are located at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185328.aspx.

I also found the reference listed above by chaiy was very useful.  Here it is again: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to