# Linker error LNK2019 (unresolved symbol) with OpenCV 2.4, CvBlob library, and Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

I've spent the last hour or two trying to hunt this problem down and can't seem to get it right. I am using OpenCV with MS VS 2012 RC, and to this point it has worked quite well (one bug dealing with the newer Mat container, but fine otherwise). I have a previously written application I am trying to port (from GCC/G++), which used the cvblob.dll library from [here](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/). I have recompiled the cvblob library with VS2012 (my previous version was compiled with MinGW and worked flawlessly), and managed to create both a DLL and an import library .LIB.

The application compiles properly, but the one spot where I use the cvblob library is now my source of error, because the linker cannot find the symbol for the cvLabel function in the library. This is the complete error message I get from VS2012:

ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>imageinput.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvLabel referenced in function "public: class std::vector,class std::allocator > > _*thiscall ImageInput::getROI(class cv::Mat,class cv::Mat)" (?getROI@ImageInput@@QAE?AV?$vector@V?$Rect*@H@cv@@V?$allocator@V?$Rect_@H@cv@@@std@@@std@@VMat@cv@@0@Z)
1>C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I'm not certain whether this is a problem with the cvblob library itself, my current binary for it, or just the process I used to compile it. I will gladly furnish any information I can upon request. Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

You obviously didn't link needed library in project settings. Try to add all OpenCV/CvBlob libs in linker properties of your prooject. See [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Also look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474218/unresolved-external-symbol-error-when-importing-libraries-for-opencv2-3-in-visua).

Comment: CvBlob.dll IS listed in my additional dependencies. That's what makes this so perplexing. I tried it with the .dll version, and then making my own .lib to go with it.

Comment: I read through that discussion while searching/researching prior to my post. Unfortunately, the wisdom gained from it was not enough to fix my problem. The good news is that I have found another solution, by using the class SimpleBlobDetector, included in OpenCV's features2d library, and extending it for my own needs. Since I was not having any linking issues with the OpenCV libs themselves, my project is able to continue.