# OpenCV downloaded from NuGet giving Unresolved Externals LNK2019

Tags: c++, opencv

I downloaded OpenCV from NuGet on MSVS 2017, and ran a code I had found on this very site:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("C:\\Users\\Chubak\\Pictures\\index.jpg");
    if (image.empty())
        return -1;
    imshow("TEST", image);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

But when I run the code I get this extremely unintelligible errors that I don't understand:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OpenCLTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>OpenCLTest.cpp
1>OpenCLTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>OpenCLTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0_InputArray@cv@@QAE@ABVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>OpenCLTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>OpenCLTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>OpenCLTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>OpenCLTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>OpenCLTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function _main
1>c:\users\chubak\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\OpenCLTest\Debug\OpenCLTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "OpenCLTest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I understand that unresolved externals error is related to missing obj files but don't they come with the NuGet Package?

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474218/unresolved-external-symbol-error-when-importing-libraries-for-opencv2-3-in-visua) question but all the links given in the answers are no longer working, so this may or may not be a duplicate.